# Merge array of arrays containing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects, each containing arrays and I want to merge them if each array contains `display: true`.
I'm very new to array manipulation, and a nudge in the correct way would be very much appreciated.

Example array:

```
{
    "first": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "display": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "display": false
        }
    ],
    "second": [
        {
            "name": "Sarah",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "display": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of expected result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "display": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "display": true
    }
]
```

I already have javascript code to set each `display` key to true/false based on search query.
I just need the array merged to match the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all values and filter the flat array.

```js
const
    data = { first: [{ name: "John", surname: "Doe", display: true }, { name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", display: false }], second: [{ name: "Sarah", surname: "Doe", display: true }] },
    result = Object
        .values(data)
        .flat()
        .filter(({ display }) => display);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reducer and filter the values within on the `display` property value. Finally flatten the result:

```js
const mergedByDisplay = Object.entries({
    "first": [{
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "display": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "display": false
      }
    ],
    "second": [{
      "name": "Sarah",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "display": true
    }]
  })
  .reduce((acc, [_, val]) => [...acc, val.filter(v => v.display)], [])
  .flat();
console.log(mergedByDisplay);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```